# Rename [lotusrb] to [hanami]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Lotus was [renamed to Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/blog/2016/01/22/lotus-is-now-hanami.html) to prevent trademark issues.

Can a moderator please merge [lotusrb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotusrb) into [hanami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hanami) and possibily add [lotusrb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotusrb) as a synonym of [hanami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hanami)?

Comment: A tag synonym seems like a good idea; but with only 8 questions with the old tag, updating the existing questions seems like something that you or any other one person could do on his own.

Comment: @DanNeely I agree completely (you beat me to it!). I think a full rename would be best, with a note added to the tag wiki. By the time Hinami leaves beta (v 1.0), it will be known as that, and no longer Lotus (probably)

Comment: @DanNeely this is what I did with the other tag (`lotusrb`). The reason why I asked a synonym is to avoid potential new questions with the legacy tag. If that's not reasonable, I'll be happy to go ahead and update the questions editing them.